# Raising an event on user control from parent

Tags: c#, events, user-controls

I have a user control that has the following overridden event:

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left )
        DoSomething();
}
```

When I place the user control on my Main Form, this event is not fired.
How can I access this event from Parent form?

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        Move(pt.X,pt.Y);//Move is a function within the usercontrol
    else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        Move(pt.X,pt.Y);
   //other conditions
   e.Handled = false;
}
```

I need the parent to be notified on this event

Comment: are you sure the user control has keyboard focus when you are pressing the key? I can't see why it shouldn't be fired. I also do not understand if you are trying to bubble the event to the main form or not.

Comment: Rotem, the user control was a windows form, tranformed in a usercontrol.It worked perfectly. Now i turned into a usercontrol and want to fire actions from a parent windows form. I have the same problem with an other project, when I built a calculator and turned into a userControl. Now I put it into a windows form and the buttons do not respond

Comment: It sounds like the solution should be a public method on the usercontrol which invokes the onKeyDown method, though you mentioned you tried that and it didn't work. At what part did it not work?

Comment: I've posted this suggestion as an answer. If this is not what you are trying to achieve please clarify.

Comment: Hello there, I've posted an updated answer with what I believe is what you are looking for. However please note you're getting a few people giving conflicting answers because the question is not particularly clear. I don't think this is a difficult problem to solve but do in future try to give clear instructions about what you are trying to achieve. You'll get a much better response! Best regards,

Comment: It's true, we've answered three different questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to invoke the `OnKeyDown` method of the user control from within the parent form.
This is the main form class:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private UserControl1 myControl;

    public Form1()
    {
        myControl = new UserControl1();
        Controls.Add(myControl);
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        myControl.InvokeOnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

And this is the User Control:

```
public class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        MessageBox.Show("Key Down Fired!");
    }

    public void InvokeOnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

**Edit regarding arrow keys:** the arrow keys are not normally considered to be input keys and therefore are not passed on to the key methods. To change this you must override the `IsInputKey` method as such:

```
 protected override bool IsInputKey(Keys e)
 {
     if (e == Keys.Up || e == Keys.Down ||
         e == Keys.Left || e == Keys.Right) return true;
     return base.IsInputKey(e);
 }
```

Comment: Rotem, I tried your solution, did not work, but I debugged it and realized that it works for different keys, except arrow keys. I searched some solutions for that, but did not find anything usefull.Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following your updated question and code example posted, if you want the parent Form to be notified that a move operation took place, you need to create an event in the UserControl and subscribe to it in the parent form. This could be achieved in the following example. Please let me know if this solves your problem, else please post further detail.

Best regards

```
// Define custom EventArgs to pass into the Move event
public class MoveEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private Point _movePoint;
    public MoveEventArgs(Point movePoint)
    {
        _movePoint = _movePoint;
    }

    public Point MovePoint { get { return _movePoint; } } 
}

// Define a custom user control that raises an event to subscribers on move
public class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public event EventHandler<MoveEventArgs> Moved;

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Left)
        {
            Move(pt.X,pt.Y);//Move is a function within the usercontrol
            OnMoved(pt);
        }   
        else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Right)
        {
            Move(pt.X,pt.Y);
            OnMoved(pt);
        }
       //other conditions
       e.Handled = false;
    }

    // Raises a custom event, Moved 
    protected void OnMoved(Point movePoint)
    {
        var handler = Moved;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new MoveEventArgs(movePoint);
        }
    }
}

// How to subscribe to the event (and be notified of move)
public class MyParentForm : Form
{
    public MyParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _myUserControl.Moved += new EventHandler<MoveEventArgs>(MyUserControl_Moved);
    }

    private void MyUserControl_Moved(object sender, MoveEventArgs e)
    {
        // e.MovePoint now contains the point that the usercontrol was moved to
        // this event will fire whenever the user presses Left or Right arrow
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I shall edit my comment. So, you wish to be notified of OnKeyDown of the usercontrol in the parent form? Did you try just hooking into the event? E.g. UserControl.KeyDown += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(myForm.KeyDownOfUserControl)

Comment: The problem is that the override OnKeyDown is protected, I have no access to it. I tried to add another method on child(public) and then repass EventArgs to the overridden event, but it did not work. Any ideas?Thanks

Comment: Andrew,still, I need to keep the functionality of user control. I need to be able to use the user control with the onkeyDown event in other applications and not repeat the actions of keydown in every application.

Comment: But you also stated you want to access the event from MainForm. Perhaps you could clarify what it is you are trying to do? The code example in the question is very brief. 

For example, are you trying to "DoSomething()" within the usercontrol but notify external subscribers that something has happened?

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: thanks for pointing me to the right point. I used your way to raise event in an elevator-like way in my custom control (it's a treeview with HierarchicalDataTemplate, and I need to raise the selected event from the child to the root, then to my Window). I wonder if there's some other more elegant way?

Comment: @HoàngLong yes, look up the EventAggregator pattern. In particular there are third party implementations such as the one in Unity (Prism). At the core its just a message broker. Injected via dependency injection to ViewModels, or accessed statically in view code-behind you can publish/subscribe anywhere in the app without coupling (usercontrols don't need to know about each other)

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson: many thanks! Hope you have a nice weekend :)